# Powermockito mock operation on hierarchy level class

Tags: junit4, powermockito

My app has hierarchy level class objects as follows.

Package com.sample.folder1;

```
  Public class ParentClass{ }
```

Package com.sample.folder2;

```
  Public class Childclass1 extends ParentClass{  }
```

Unit piece under test package:

```
 @Test
 Public void testMocking{

   Childclass1 obj = Powermockito.mock(Chilclass1.class);
 }
```

When I execute above junit in eclipse it throws

```
"VerifyError: Inconsistent stackmap frames....."
```

Please suggest mocking on hierarchy classes on same and different packages.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add -noverify (Java 8) or -XX:-UseSplitVerifier (Java 7) as vm parameter.